# Can't access remote MYSQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have problem connecting SQL with php. I don't even get an SQL error, just an ugly PHP error message:

> "Warning: mysql_connect(): in
>   C:\wamp\www\guildcreator\include\sql_conn.php on 
>   line 19 Call Stack
>     Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0004  252040  {main}( )
>   ..\sub.php:0 2  0.0009  255208  include(
>   'C:\wamp\www\guildcreator\include\sql_conn.php' ) ..\sub.php:5
>   3 0.0009  256344  mysql_connect ( )"

At first I thought that I wasn't creating a connection to the server. I tried various different combinations of the same address, with and without the port number. I don't understand why I am getting this error, because if `mysql_connect` fails I should be seeing the `die()` message.

I read something about the `mysql_` functions being old and unsupported, maybe that's my problem? Any help would be great :-)

Here's the code that I am using:

```
$hostname = 'lolisrael.co.il:3306';
$sqluser = 'XXXXXX';
$sqlpass = 'XXXXXXXXX';

$link = mysql_connect($hostname, $sqluser, $sqlpass) or die("error zzzzz"); 
if ($link)
    $db = mysql_select_db('_db', $link) or die("no db found");
```

the submite page for reference:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['free_text'])) 
{
    echo "<p>".$_POST['free_text']."</p>";
    include "include/sql_conn.php";
    if(isset($db))
    {
        $free_text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['free_text']);
        $sql = "INSERT
            INTO
            orhalimi_test_conn(free_text)
            VALUES ('{$free_text}')";
        if(mysql_query($sql))
            echo "ITS WORK!!!";

    }
}           
?>
```

Comment: What's line 19, also try using PDO instead of mysql_connect

Comment: line 19 is `$link = mysql_connect($hostname, $sqluser, $sqlpass) or die("error zzzzz"); `

if PDO is some extantion that need to be install on the server its not possable ..

Comment: Try `echo mysql_error()` after that line and see if it says anything useful. It's probably not the cause of the problem but you shouldn't be using `mysql_` functions anymore (they are no longer supported), you should be using `mysqli_` functions or `PDO` instead.

Comment: @OrHalimi Most PHP installations comes with PDO/MySQLi by default AFAIK, worst case you will only have to remove config comment lines on the `php.ini` file but rarely needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($link)
    $db = mysql_select_db('_db', $link) or die("no db found");
```

why would you use the mysql_select_db() function into a variable? :)
Also i recommend you to use MySQLi or PDO as from the version 5.4 the mysql_* functions are considered deprecated.

Comment: amm...that how i saw poeple do it?
i will try with mysqli, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys thanks for help, but it seem the problem was a security config of the remote server.

I will look on mysqli trough.